# AngularJS - Prefetch data without blocking

Tags: angularjs

In our application we fetch data from a service which happens to be a long running transaction at times (10+ seconds). Currently we invoke it as a part of the "Resolve" in config() of the module, this blocks the page until the service data is fetched completely.

Can we pre-fetch the data by invoking the service but not block the page execution?

Comment: Is the service code ran synchrounously? Because sync operations do block the UI

Comment: remove it from the resolve and handle it inside your page's controller  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a not so recent project I simply let the services I called in Resolve return promises.

```
    var resolve = {
        localize : 'localize',
        AttackService : 'AttackService.promise',
        CharacterService : 'CharacterService.promise',
        StateRestorer: 'StateRestorer'
    };

~function(){
"use strict";

/**
 * @class EVD.services.StateRestorer
 *
 * For now where we load up all the state about our hero, etc when we
 * refresh the game
 *
 **/
EVD.modules.service
    .factory('StateRestorer', ['models', 'HeroAPI', 'BattleAPI', '$rootScope','$q',
        function(models, HeroAPI, BattleAPI, $rootScope, $q) {


            var principal;

            var fns = []; //List of functions to execute
            principal = HeroAPI.principal();
            fns.push(principal);


            var character = HeroAPI.character();
            fns.push(character.$promise);
            var mounted = HeroAPI.mounted();
            fns.push(mounted.$promise);
            var recentKills =  BattleAPI.recentKills();
            fns.push(recentKills.$promise);
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $q.all(fns).then(
                function(data) {

                    $rootScope.user =     data[0];
                    EVD.common.extractPayload(models.get('playerState.character'), data[1]);
                    EVD.common.extractPayload(models.get('playerState.equipment'), data[2]);
                    models.set('playerState.recentKills', data[3].result);
                    deferred.resolve();

                }
            );


            return deferred.promise;
    }])
```

}();

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Cetia. Why not just call the service it inside the controller? Because it's a long running task you can make use of the third function for promises:

```
myTask.then(function(success) {
  // Do stuff with the result
}, function(error) {
  // Handle error
}, function(progress) {
  // Publish progress to the UI
});
```

This way you can fetch the data but not block the UI.